# Silverlight 4 - Adding new Rows via the DataGrid control

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm busy building an application where a user can copy and paste data to a silver light data-grid. If there are no rows the rows should be added via code and the rows should be updated with the pasted value. The datagrid is bound to a observablecollection.

I'm able to access the Clipboard.GetText() method to get the database but I'm not able to add datarows to the grid via code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should have a look at the [Silverlight 4 service release (September 2010)](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/09/01/silverlight-service-release-september-2010-gdr1.aspx)? It adds support to enable Add New Row capabilities in DataGrid control.

Comment: I've installed it but can't seem to see the changes they made.

Comment: @Johab J v Rensburg: Did you install the updated SDK or just the runtime? You have to install the SDK to be able to get access to the new functionality. Unfortunately I'm not sure about the exact nature of the change myself.

Comment: I've installed both the Runtime and the SDK (Silverlight_developer.exe and Silverlight_SDK.exe)